# Filling a hole in object

Tags: mesh, obj

All tutorials I have checked say to do the same thing, but on my end it isn't working.

You should select vertices around the hole, and press alt+f. But for me blender shows message "No faces filled". So I'm kind of stuck here, because I have tried to do this a bunch of times already and blender does not seem to start cooperating.

[Image](https://i.ibb.co/KmwdZJH/Screenshot-2.png) of the hole.

Comment: Please add your image directly into the question, either with the Image icon at the top of the question or by dragging and dropping the file directly into the question field. Having to click external links to see images is not helpful. Have you checked for duplicate vertices round the hole using 'M' > Merge by Distance?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first off, make sure you don't have any doubled geometry, that might be causing issues, like where you're selecting what looks like 10 edges that are part of the same circle but are actually parts of two circles directly on top of each other.

[image]

Then you can do one of three things:

Just "F" to fill the face as a big n-gon.

[image]

`Alt+F` which is almost the same thing, except it runs the fill command with "Beauty" checked.

[image]

Or finally, and what I think might be the best for this scenario, is to push `Ctrl+F` and then select *Grid Fill*.

[image]

Which will do it's best to fill the circle with all-quads.

[image]